# Including cypress tests in CI

Tags: linux, npm, cypress, cicd

I am trying to include my cypress tests in CI/CD chain (pipeline). Server where the env will be created and cypress tests run is Linux server. Can I install all cypress/Linux dependencies using NPM, or what is the best option for this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, and you can easily execute on CI with Cypress GitHub Action.
You can refer to more details, via Cypress GitHub action repository
https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action

Simple Example https://gist.github.com/NilukaSripalim/36e093530887ce6e5f5c889b2f2547e9

```
# CI name
name: Cypress GitHub Actions

# The on key is used to define when
# the CI should be triggered, aka Event
on:
  # When someone push or merge a pull request
  # inside the master branch
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  # When someone create a pull request from
  # the master branch
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

# A job is a set of steps that execute on the same runner.
# The jobs can be run in parallel or sequentially and can 
# have many steps.
# In this case, I created a single job with many steps
# since the configuration is pretty simple but
# I could have created a different structure using parallel jobs.
# Each job uses an own runner.
jobs:
  # Job name
  suite:
    # OS of the runner
    # # We're running on ubuntu-latest, nothing special
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # A step is an individual task that can run commands in a job
    # and share the same runner.
    # Each step can run a ready-to-use action or a bash command
    steps:
      # Runner meaningful name
      # It's a step's name
      # As usual, we simply checkout the project
      - name: Checkout
        # In this line basically our workflow checks our repository 
        # allowing you to run actions against own code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

        # This action is provided by Cypress.
      - name: Setup and run Cypress
        # This is a cypress ready-to-use action
        # that setups the runner installing the 
        # dependencies using NPM and installing Cypress
        # Execute all tests cases in project.
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        # The action accepts parameters.
        # You should read the documentation before using an action
        # to understand what it does under the hood.
        # Here Run the tests on Chrome & Headless Mode.
        with:
          browser: chrome
          headless: true
          record: true
        # after the test run completes
        # store videos and any screenshots
        # NOTE: screenshots will be generated only if E2E test failed
        # thus we store screenshots only on failures
        # Alternative: create and commit an empty cypress/screenshots folder
        # to always have something to upload  
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        if: failure()
        with:
          name: cypress-screenshots
          path: cypress/screenshots
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        if: always()
        with:
          name: cypress-videos
          path: cypress/videos
```